# Open and search website from code

Tags: c#, browser

I would like to open a new browser page...

```
Process.Start("http://www.wolframalpha.com/");
```

and automatically paste in some search text...

```
string inputString = "x^2+y^2 = 1";
```

and then run the search without the user having to do anything. How can this be done?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do this..

```
Process.Start(
     "http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i="
     + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("x^2+y^2 = 1")
     + "&dataset=");
```

it will open your default browser ( or a new tab in an existing browser)  and then encodes the search term into a request.

Answer (score 1):

The first param is the process to start, and the second are the arguments.

```
Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "www.google.com?q=my+search+term");
```

Comment: its better to open system's default browser. most users decided to use a real web browser.anything rather than IE.

Comment: The Google search works, any idea how to make a WolframAlpha search work? I don't do any web programming so I'm just trying to get "fast plots" by supplying the function string to a search.

Comment: @pylover true, but I don't know how to open the default. I think Keith's answer got it right.

Comment: Yes , the keith's answer gives you a tip

Answer (score -1):

This should solve your problem:

```
var query = "x^2+y^2 = 1";
Process.Start("iexplore.exe", System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode("http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=" + query));
```

Comment: whats about System's default browser?